# Elasticsearch: index first char of string

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, mappings

I'm using version 5.3.

I have a text field `a`. I'd like to aggregate on the first char of `a`. I also need the entire original value.

I'm assuming the most efficient way is to have a keyword field `a.firstLetter` with a custom normalizer. I've tried to achieve this with a pattern replace char filter but am struggling with the regexp.

Am I going at this entirely wrong? Can you help me?

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried.

settings.json

```
{
  "settings":  {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "char_filter": {
          "first_char": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "(?<=^.)(.*)",
            "replacement": ""
          }
        }
        "normalizer": {
          "first_letter": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": ["first_char"]
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mappings.json

```
{
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "text",
      "index_options": "positions",
      "fields": {
        "firstLetter": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "first_letter"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get no buckets when I try to aggregate like so:

```
"aggregations": {
  "grouping": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "a.firstLetter"
    }
  }
}
```

So basically my approach was "replace all but the first char with an empty string." The regexp is something I was able to gather by googling.

**EDIT 2**
I had misconfigured the normalizer (I've fixed the examples). The correct configuration reveals that normalizers do not support pattern replace char filters due to [issue 23142](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23142). Apparently support for it will be implemented earliest in version 5.4.

So are there any other options? I'd hate to do this in code, by adding a field in the doc for the first letter, since I'm using Elasticsearch features for every other aggregation.

Comment: Share the code sample what you tried .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `truncate` filter with a length of one

```
PUT foo
{
  "mappings": {
    "bar" : {
      "properties": {
        "name" : {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "settings":  {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer" : {
          "my_analyzer" : {
            "type" : "custom",
            "tokenizer" : "keyword",
            "filter" : [ "my_filter", "lowercase" ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_filter": {
            "type": "truncate",
            "length": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET foo/_analyze
{
  "field" : "name",
  "text" : "New York"
}

# response
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "n",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That works but requires to enable fielddata on the text field. It's not recommended but I guess it's ok for this use case. Thanks!

Comment: oh, indeed. You could use a `gsub` processor with an ingest pipeline to prevent this.